# Windows batch script ends unexpectedly

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am not familiar with windows batches.
I'm trying to write a script that will be included in a database migration script chain. It should check if SQL scripts have a hardcoded database name, and if it finds any, should warn the user, output file names, and stop the chain execution.

I reckon there are multiple problems with it..

```
set "lf=^"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (functions sprocs up views) do (
    cd %%a
    for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('findstr /lism "[MyDatabase]" *.sql') do (
        if not [%%b] == [] (
            call :append %%a\%%b
        )
    )
    cd ..
)
if [%sinList%] == [] (
    echo No hardcoded names in scripts found, continuing..
    pause
) else (
    echo Cannot continue database migration until you clear out hardcoded database name in files^%lf%%lf%
    echo Files with hardcode^%lf%%lf% : %sinList%
    pause
    exit /b 1
)
goto :eof

:append
if defined sinList (
    set sinList=%sinList%%1^%lf%%lf%
) else (
    set sinList=%1^%lf%%lf%
)
goto :eof
```

Right now when I execute it I end up in `/sprocs` folder, doesn't output any results.

Turning on echo looks like this

> C:\Portal\Database.Migration>dbname_hardcode_punisher.cmd
>   C:\Portal\Database.Migration>set "lf=^"
>   C:\Portal\Database.Migration>set "sinList="
>   C:\Portal\Database.Migration>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>   C:\Portal\Database.Migration>for %a in (functions sprocs up views)  do
>   ( cd %a  for /F "tokens=*" %b in ('findstr /lism "[MyDatabase]" *.sql') do
>   (if not [%b] == [ ] (call :append %a\%b ) )  cd .. )
>   C:\Portal\Database.Migration>( cd functions  for /F "tokens=*" %b in
>   ('findstr /lism "[MyDatabase]" *.sql') do (if not [%b] == [ ] (call
>   :append functions\%b ) )  cd .. ) C:\Portal\Database.Migration>( cd
>   sprocs  for /F "tokens=*" %b in ('findstr /lism "[MyDatabase]" *.sql')
>   do (if not [%b] == [ ] (call :append sprocs\%b ) )  cd .. )
>   C:\Portal\Database.Migration\sprocs>(if not [Proc_name.sql] == []
>   (call :append sprocs\Another_proc.sql ) )

Also I'm afraid that `if [%sinList%] == []` may not return the expected results since it could have one newline?

Answer (score 0):

for the LineFeed trick to work, it needs delayed expansion (both with `lf` and the variable) and two empty lines:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set lf=^
%= don't delete =%
%= these two lines =%
set new=hello!lf!world
echo !new!
echo Hello!lf!World
```

(Q:Where are the two required empty lines? A: `%= anything =%` is not defined and therefore gets parsed as nothing (empty). Just a reminder for the programmer not to delete them; You could also use just empty lines)